# Locating the point on the triangle

Tags: geometry

The distance between $A$ and $B$ is $4$ miles, $A$ and $D$ is $10$ miles, $B$ and $D$ is $7$ miles, and we need to locate the position of the point $C$. A man starts to walk from $A$ to $B$ at a speed of $4$ miles/hour, while another man starts walking from $A$ towards $D$ at $2$ miles/hour. After visiting the point $B$, the first man wants to meet with the second man at a point between $A$ and $D$ such that they both want to meet as soon as possible. Suppose they meet at point $C$, how to locate the position of the point $C$.

What I have tried: Let's say they meet after time $t$, I can use something like this $$\frac{AB + BC}{\text{speed of person $1$}} = \frac{CA}{\text{speed of person 2}}.$$ Then find the equation of line $AD$ assuming I have the coordinates, too. Solve both the equations simultaneously for $C$. But I need a better method.

Here is a picture:

[image]

Comment: I see you are new to this site. Please draw the picture, use mathjax, and show us what you have done

Comment: There is a picture, if you click on the question.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I agree, but its much easier if you directly paste the picture in the question itself. Please update the question on what you have tried

Comment: Need to locate C, thanks

Comment: @AshleyLarson I feel like there is an argument missed, only if C should be located in terms of this argument, i suppose it to be an angle.[BAC]

Comment: @Abra001 Let's assume that we also know the coordinates of A, B and D. What do you mean when you say its an angle? Thanks

Comment: What about A does he have a stable velocity ? I mean when he quits B.

Comment: @Abra001 Yes, the velocity remains same all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set: $x=BC$, $y=AC$, $\alpha=\angle BAD$. The two men meet if $x=2y-4$.

From the cosine rule applied to $ABD$ we have $\cos\alpha=67/80$.

Apply now the cosine rule to $ABC$:
$$
x^2=4^2+y^2-8y\cos\alpha.
$$
Substitute here $x$ and $\cos\alpha$ as given above and solve for $y$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am not a mathematician so having a bit trouble understanding the answer. I would read about the cosine rule.  If possible could you explain a bit more?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines

Comment: I understood the answer except how you came to this conclusion  "The two men meet if x=2y−4."

Comment: Got it thanks a lot!

Comment: Just wanted to extend this question a little bit. If the person walking from A to D reaches the point D before the person walking from A to B to D. Is it possible to locate the point C still between A and D or it will be outside AD outside D. Thank you.

Comment: If the speed of the first man is reduced, it may well happen that they won't meet before $D$. But the formula given above also works in that case, provided $x$ is given by $x=(v_1/v_2)y-4$, where $v_1$ and $v_2$ are the speeds of the two men.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I don't think there is a shortcut to this:

from this picture: $X=2tsin\alpha=4sin\alpha$

$X^2+(t+t'-2tcos\alpha)^2=(2t')^2$

$16sin^2\alpha+(2+t'-4cos\alpha)^2=4t'^2$

One equation with one unknown, once $\alpha$ known, find $t'$ then $t+t'$.